# How to make text appear on top of the image when hovering?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When a mouse hovering over the image, the image will be blurred and there will be text showing up on top of the image. I tried it myself using the code below but it appeared that the "text" move outside the image when hovering
...can anyone tell me why?

Code:

Html:

```
<span class ="row_1">
<a href="#">
<div class = "caption"> testing </div>
<img class = "img_link" src="image/food/food1.jpg" />
</a>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.caption
{
display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
    $('a').hover(
    function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img'),
     caption = $(this).find('div');
     caption.width(image.width());
     caption.height(image.height());
     caption.fadeIn();
    },
    function(){
     var image= $(this).find('img'),
        caption = $(this).find('div');

    caption.width(image.width());
    caption.height(image.height());
    caption.fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: "test was out of the box" ? what do you mean ? what is it that you exactly want ?

Comment: _"but didn't work"_ ohhh, that just says it all! not... :(

Comment: There shouldn't be a space between the attribute and the value, `<div class="testing">` for example

Comment: I think my title explain it.
When hovering a image, the text will show up inside the image

Comment: @Dale. I don't think it causes errors.

Comment: but didn't work (the "test was out of the box") :)

Comment: I dont get what you're trying to do : you want word to appear when hovering an image ?

Comment: just so that you know, nobody can see that image and nobody can understand if the text will actually show up inside the image

Comment: "It didn't work" is not really describing what did happen and what you expected to happen.  The cryptic "out of the box" comment makes no sense to me, sorry.

Comment: @gdoron no I was just considering whether to remove my comment or not, been a long day I shouldn't be here. I'll leave it for prosperity.

Comment: I edited and the problem should be more clear right now

Comment: you really need to explain what you're trying to do. 'word appear when hovering href image' -- ok, so a word appears linked to the onHover event of an image tag. Where does this word come from? Where did you get your sample code? Does it require any other libraries (like jQuery for example)? Why did it not work? What does your HTML documentlook like? Did you include jQuery?

Comment: Sorry, it should be much more clear now

Comment: Do you want this http://jsfiddle.net/heera/6v8Tb/

Comment: exactly, thanks! i would study the code a bit.

Comment: @SheikhHeera, I hope you dont mind me using your fiddle in my demo. ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, I had to correct your HTML. A `div` (block-level element) is *not* a valid child of either a `span` or `a` elements (both of which are in-line elements). So, amended your HTML to the following:

```
<span class="row_1">
    <a href="#">
        <span class="caption">testing</span>
        <img class="img_link" src="http://davidrhysthomas.co.uk/img/dexter.png" />
    </a>
</span>​
```

That said, I'd suggest, if possible, using plain CSS for this:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.caption {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #333; /* for browsers that don't understand rgba() notation */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #f90;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1em;
}
a:hover .caption {
    display: block;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J8r34/1/).

You can, with CSS3 transitions, even implement the fade-in transition as well (which gracefully degrades for those browsers that don't understand/implement transitions, albeit in this example you might have to use a Microsoft proprietary filter for older-IE compliance):

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}
.caption {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #333; /* for browsers that don't understand rgba() notation */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    color: #f90;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.1em;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}
a:hover .caption {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s linear;
    -o-transition: all 1s linear;
    -ms-transition: all 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: all 1s linear;
    transition: all 1s linear;
}​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J8r34/2/).

If you must use jQuery then I'd suggest keeping it very, very simple:

```
​$('.row_1 a').hover(
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(1000);
    });​​​​​​​​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/J8r34/3/).

References:

- [CSS `transition`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/).
- [`fadeIn()`](http://api.juery.com/fadeIn/).
- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.juery.com/fadeOut/).
- [`find()`](http://api.juery.com/find/).

Comment: +1 for a sexy, cross-browser, javascriptless graceful-degradation/progressive-enhancement solution!

Comment: Why, thank you kindly! ...though now I feel a little bad, since I added a jQuery fall-back. =/

Answer (score 1):

You dont need Javascript for this. This snippet below is enough to bring up the caption.

```
a:hover .caption { display: block; }
```

But the caption has to be positioned correctly first.

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Starx/9MshR/)